# Primefaces Dynamic Tree: Null grandParent reference in selectedNode

Tags: java, tree, primefaces, nullpointerexception, parent

I have a dynamic tree using Primefaces 3.2/JSF2.0/Mojarra/JBoss6. 
I'm adding childs succesfully at my onNodeExpand method.

```
    public void onNodeExpand(NodeExpandEvent event){
     if(selectedNode.type.equals("GrandParent")){
                  TreeNode parent = new DefaultTreeNode(data, event.getTreeNode());
     //parent.setParent(event.getTreeNode()); 
      parent.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode(null, parent));

     }

     if(selectedNode.type.equals("Parent")){
      TreeNode child = new DefaultTreeNode(childData, event.getTreeNode());
      child.getChildren().add(new DefaultTreeNode(null, child));
     }
   }
```

the tree is displayed correctly, but I get a NPE when I try to access the grandparent of a "Child" node.

```
    public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event){
       granPaNode = (NodeDto) event.getTreeNode().getParent().getParent().getData();
    }
```

this code works well at primefaces 2.2 but no more at PF 3.2

any idea how to workaround this without mapping logicData in another structure?

thanks a lot.